# Can a Progress Client & ODBC Client access a Personal database at the same time?

Tags: odbc, 4gl, progress-db

Working on Progress 9.1E on a Windows box. We've got a standard 4GL GUI application up and running which connects to a series of personal databases running on the same box. It's sort of like a big graphical catalogue application with ordering capabilities.

Anyhow, we're looking to run a .Net application on the same box and Progress supplies a Merant ODBC driver along with it's runtime.

My question is, can I have the 4GL GUI client application up and running and connected to the Progress databases while at the same time connecting and running the .Net application which connects via an OBDC System DSN to the same databases?

These "personal" databases are traditionally single user, but I'm wondering (or have heard through rumours) that you can actually run an ODBC client in addition to a 4GL client on the same box at the same time.

Truth to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run both a 4GL client and an ODBC client, but you can't run them both single user at the same time. You'll need to start a server for each of the DBs you want concurrent access to. You can run the server process on the same machine, if you have the licence, if that helps.